# After deploying the USA AWS beanstalk environment in ec2 (ec2 in China),I cannot get platform information under the aws china beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

To deploy the USA AWS beanstalk environment in China EC2 instance, I use the following shell command：

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-1 ~]#echo -e "[profile eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = 123\naws_secret_access_key = 234" > /root/.aws/config 
[root@ip-10-0-0-1 ~]#echo -e "[profile eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = 123\naws_secret_access_key = 234" > /root/.aws/credentials 
[root@ip-10-0-0-1 ~]#eb init worldcup --region us-west-1 --platform "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-1::platform/Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.7" 
[root@ip-10-0-0-1 ~]#eb deploy "worldcup-dev" --version 6ad83ed9f599a8c9c967ef2f7168127f8dee2123-675
```

It's finished.

Then I use aws access key in Chinese region to get the platform information of china aws beanstalk specified environment:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-1 ~]#echo -e "[profile eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = 456\naws_secret_access_key = 789" > /root/.aws/config 
[root@ip-10-0-0-1 ~]#echo -e "[profile eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = 456\naws_secret_access_key = 789" > /root/.aws/credentials 
[root@ip-10-0-0-1 ~]#eb use chinacup-dev --region cn-north-1
[root@ip-10-0-0-1 ~]#eb platform show --region cn-north-1

ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - Platform 'arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-1::platform/Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.7' is in a different region.
```

How should I solve the above problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-1::platform/Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.7` is **not** valid in `cn-north-1`.

Open `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` and change the `default_platform` to the equivalent platform ARN in the `cn-north-1` region. You can find the equivalent platform ARN in the `cn-north-1` region by executing:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk list-platform-versions --region cn-north-1 --filters "Type=PlatformName,Operator='contains',Values='Tomcat 8'" | grep "PlatformArn"
```